# "unintuitive" vs "nonintuitive" vs"counter-intuitive"

Tags: is-it-a-word

Today I found out that despite using and hearing it frequently, "unintuitive" is not a word.

I searched english.stackexchange and found countless answers where the word is used.

It also seems that while all dictionaries (except Wiktionary) do not list "unintutive", some dictionaries list "non-intuitive"/"nonintutitve" (Merriam Webster) while others only list "counter-intuitive" (Cambridge).

I see no good reason why it should not be a (correct) word.
Can you?

Very unintuitive...

Comment: This is interesting. Consider http://reword.me/blog/2010/10/this-word-should-be-a-word/ where a comment says that it does exist in the 1993 print OED. Have you checked physical dictionaries as well?

Comment: Hello, The AEB. Dictionaries pick up on currency, how often words are used in various media and hopefully conversations. Wiktionary, while not usually considered the best edited of English dictionaries, does carry the most headwords. Other dictionaries may well pick up on increased use in coming editions. //  ' "[U]nintuitive" is not a word' is a strong claim. What supporting evidence do you have for this (OED itself states that non-inclusion in their unparalleled work must not be taken as evidence of non-wordness)?

Comment: Anything less than 20 years old is sheer speculation.

Comment: That should probably be (OED itself states that non-inclusion in their unparalleled work must not be taken as **proof** of non-wordness).

Comment: ***unintuitive*** is [in the full OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/214653?redirectedFrom=unintuitive#eid) anyway. As its own dedicated entry, no less!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for your answer. The evidence for the claim was provided in the question. However, as you said in another comment here, who decides whether a candidate is a 'legitimate word'?

Comment: @dubious Thanks for the link!

Comment: But 'It ... seems that ... all dictionaries (except Wiktionary) do not list "unintutive"' is not a sufficient reason for the statement 'Today I found out that despite using and hearing it frequently, "unintuitive" is not a word.' Have you a more convincing reason? // In addition, 'It also seems that ...' does not point to a causal relationship. // Wiktionary is the 'largest' English dictionary in terms of headwords, and is almost guaranteed to have some words that others haven't yet picked up on. Of course, it is more prone to allow in dubious candidates.

Answer (score 3):

> **unintuitive** (adj.)
>
> 1842   W. Hamilton *Diss*. in T. Reid Wks. 767   The unintuitive
> judgments.
>
> **unintuitively** (adv.)
>
> 1904   B. Russell in *Mind* 13 347   The same object can be presented
> either intuitively or unintuitively.
>
> 1980   *Notre Dame Jrnl. Formal Logic* 21 351   The logic is
> unintuitively cumbersome since it is of the axiomatic type.
>
> **non-intuitive** (adj.)
>
> 1856   H. F. Brownson tr. J. L. Balmes *Fund. Philos.* 118   Ideas
> purely intellectual, either intuitive or non-intuitive.
>
> 1981   Icarus 47 220   The nonintuitive dynamical environment of
> Phobos and Deimos. (OED online)

> **nonintuitive** (adj.)
>
> Not intuitive: such as
>
> a. Not readily learned or understood
>
> *Working with a nonintuitive interface causes many programmers to make mistakes. — Andrew Stellman and Jennifer Greene*
>
> b. Not based on or agreeing with intuition
>
> *nonintuitive results* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonintuitive)

> **counterintuitive** (adj.)
>
> Contrary to what one would intuitively expect
>
> *As counterintuitive as it may seem, the universe has no center, and it has no boundary.— Jim Bell* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterintuitive)

> **unintuitive** {adj} (in particular, counterintuitive; counter to what one's intuition expects)--SEE: counterintuitive [Joseph Lesser;
> *English/Portuguese Dictionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/English_Portuguese_Dictionary/GtKoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=english/portuguese%20dictionary%20unintuitive&pg=PT3466&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

Google Ngram:
[image]

If we combine the hyphenated and non-hyphenated forms, it appears that *non(-)intuitive* and *unintuitive* are roughly equivalent in frequency today, at least looking at their Ngrams. However, *non* is trending down, and *un* up.

---

> People have found the assignments of degrees to complexes
> **unintuitive** and unmotivated. ... Similar **unintuitive** results are obtained when the sentences stand in non-formal logical relations.
> [B. Hale et al.; *A Companion to the Philosophy of Language*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Companion_to_the_Philosophy_of_Languag/insnDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive&pg=PT1490&printsec=frontcover)
> (2017)

> Although the non-ramified or simple theory of types has attracted much
> subsequent work, all type theory suffers from a problem of
> **unintuitive** duplication. [Simon Blackburn; *The Oxford Dictionary of Philosphy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Oxford_Dictionary_of_Philosophy/Mc55CwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dictionary%20unintuitive&pg=PA485&printsec=frontcover) (2016)

> The **unintuitive** equilibrium is that John works less hard and gets
> a B grade whether he is high or low ability and is given an executive
> job; if John did get an A grade, he would be given a manual job.
> [Edward Cartwright; *Behavioral Economics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Behavioral_Economics/dCtEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive&pg=PT271&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> If the failure of BI-intuitions showed that the norms of reasoning are
> sometimes unintuitive, the same will be true of many laws of the
> tutor's theories of deducibility and probability. They, too, will be
> **unintuitive**. In the former case, theoretical intuitions were summoned to relieve our anxiety about BI-**unintuitiveness**. In the
> present case, the **unintuitive** nature of these laws of logic and
> probability theory may itself require explaining away. If we resort to
> the same measure as before, we will offer theoretical intuitions in
> support of the **unintuitive** case. Since the **unintuitive** cases
> reside in the ... [John Woods; *Paradox and Paraconsistency*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Paradox_and_Paraconsistency/lTGyNYe_E-IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive&pg=PA319&printsec=frontcover)
> (2003)

> Perhaps one could still mount a common sense-based objection to the
> MWI, if one thought that the **unintuitive** features of the MWI
> outweigh its intuitive causal explanations. [R. Peels et al.;
> *Scientific Challenges to Common Sense Philosophy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Scientific_Challenges_to_Common_Sense_Ph/qAfoDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive&pg=PT59&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> Although the transformation preserved the configuration of the
> intuitive and **unintuitive** pooling equilibria, it was done to
> induce decisions in early matchings to correspond to the case where
> low-ability people do get an education, and high-ability people do
> not. [D. Davis and C. Holt; *Experimental Economics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Experimental_Economics/lygsEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive&pg=PA405&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> Any version of Interest-Relative Invariantism (IRI) will have certain
> **unintuitive** consequences. I have tried to argue that it is not clear
> that the **unintuitive** consequences of IRI are any worse than the
> **unintuitive** consequences of other standard epistemological theories. [Jason Stanley; *Knowledge and Practical Interests*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Knowledge_and_Practical_Interests/vueaTKto730C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover)
> (2005)

> First, the degree to which Haji's conclusions are **unintuitive** must
> be weighted against how **unintuitive** it is to reject one or more of
> his premises. [Derk Pereboom; *Living Without Free Will*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Living_Without_Free_Will/WTfvhJw9kiAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive&pg=PA144&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

---

A Google News search turned up (headlines only):

> David Spiegelhalter and Anthony Masters, "Exponential growth is
> **unintuitive** and can be frightening" [TheGuardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/theobserver/commentisfree/2021/dec/19/exponential-growth-is-unintuitive-and-can-be-frightening) (19 Dec. 2021)

> Fiona Truant, "**Unintuitive** dining space hosts two killer food
> options" [Colorodo Springs Indy](https://www.csindy.com/food_and_culture/food_and_drink/unintuitive-dining-space-hosts-two-killer-food-options/article_a96ca736-36ce-11ec-a914-df73eada0295.html) (Oct. 27, 2021)

> Danika Ellis, "BOOK PIRATES BUY MORE BOOKS, AND OTHER **UNINTUITIVE**
> BOOK PIRACY FACTS" [BookRiot.com](https://bookriot.com/book-pirates/) (July 26, 2021)

> Michael Perrigo, "Google Tasks is getting rid of its **unintuitive**
> navigation drawer and will let you star entries"
> [ChromeUnboxed.com](https://chromeunboxed.com/google-tasks-starred-items-navigation-update) (Aug. 25, 2021)

> Minh Nguyen, "Immersive **unintuitive** game design"
> [HoniSoit.com](http://honisoit.com/2021/05/immersive-unintuitive-game-design/) (May 2, 2021)

---

The question remains, at least for me, whether *unintuitive* is sometimes intended or understood to be stronger than *non-intuitive*, i.e., *counter-intuitive* or fully contrary.

I found this quiz in [Jon Marks, *Check Your English Vocabulary for Computers and Information Technology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Check_Your_English_Vocabulary_for_Comput/7wfSBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unintuitive%20nonintuitive&pg=SA2-PA5&printsec=frontcover) (2007):

> 2.5 Some useful adjectives
>
> A. Choose the best word:
>
> 1. Software that is easy to use is ...
>    a. user-easy  b. user-friendly c. usable
> 2. Software which is obvious to use is ...
>    a. intuitive b. guessable  c. comprehensible
> 3. Software which is not obvious to use is ...
>    a. **counter-intuitive** b. **unintutive** c. **non-intutive**
>    ...

Answer Key:

> 2.5 Some useful adjectives
> A: 1 b, 2 a, 3 a, 4 c, 5 a, 6 c, 7 a, 8 b, 9 c

I don't see any discussion of these words elsewhere in the book.

Comment: Now *that* is one detailed, well-researched answer.

Comment: @DjinTonic thanks for your answer!

Coincidentally, it was while typing a Slack message relating to how a certain function was unintuitive (so in the context of software), that the spell checker red-lined "unintuitive".

Comment: @DjinTonic I also agree that "counterintuitive", "nonintuitive" and "unintuitive" convey slightly different intentions. That's how perceive their usage, intuitively...

Comment: Counterintuitive means the opposite of what you expect. Un- and non- are closer to each other, meaning not intuitive, and it might just be a matter of context.

Comment: @StuartF yes that is how I interpret them, but I think some dictionaries do not.

Answer (score 0):

Unintuitive is in use. You can see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unintuitive%22&rlz=1C1CHBD_en__1002__1003&biw=1920&bih=969&sxsrf=ALiCzsa7ELn-mi1_VrsaXWyV3Un667ppvw%3A1651670198015&ei=tnxyYsQ_ysbj4Q_yi7XgBg&ved=0ahUKEwjE8sD79sX3AhVK4zgGHfJFDWwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22unintuitive%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFgAYLwBaABwAXgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) or [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unintuitive%22&rlz=1C1CHBD_en__1002__1003&sxsrf=ALiCzsaJYhfe_CuOvbfCTqzy8GNPiysKAw:1651670094291&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUiobK9sX3AhUHzTgGHcUEDSkQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&cshid=1651670220998545&biw=1920&bih=969&dpr=1).

You should not think that it is not a word. It is a legitimate word that has been underused owing to a couple of other equivalents that have been used more often.

Comment: But who decides whether a candidate is a 'legitimate word'?  << Have you ever wondered what _contrafibularities_ means (and what about _interfrastically_)?

Of course, it is an un-word ... created for the show. >> [[Blackadder Quotes; admittedly cherry-picked: there are other sources discussing pseudowords etc, even on ELU](https://blackadderquotes.com/the-blackadder-dictionary) There has to be a currency above the odd example in what is perhaps a dubious post. There may well be with 'unintuitive': have you any supporting data?